# ActiveRecord Savepoint exception in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I keep getting the following when running a spec, as per Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial:

```
Failures:

  1) User should create a new instance given valid attributes
     Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: near "SAVEPOINT": syntax error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've upgraded my sqlite 3 version to 3.7.13 on the system. Any ideas as to how to fix this so that the test passes?

Comment: please include the `user_spec.rb`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W_qThVZI_rqb09bToUaWrhxBFX6O9h8wZz7XSw0HRMM/edit - can find it here.